# C# WMI SetMTU System.ManagementException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wmi, nic, mtu

We are working on a programm to configure some NICs. 
We have to change IP Adresses, Subnetmask and the MTU. 
Everything went well except the MTU Statement:

```
public void SetMTU()
{
    ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
    {
       if (networkadapterID == (String)objMO["SettingID"])
          {                
               ManagementBaseObject setMTU;
               ManagementBaseObject newMTU = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetMTU");
               Int32 test = 9216;
               newMTU["MTU"] = test;
               setMTU = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetMTU", newMTU, null);
          }  
    }
}
```

The correct NIC ID is given. Other WMI Operations succeed but we stuck on that one with error Message: 
System.Management.ManagementException: "Die Methode ist ungültig. "

(System.Management.ManagementException: "The Method is invalid.")

We have also tried to use "test" as string or uint32 (because the microsoft docs says it's an uint32),also:

```
newMTU["MTU"] = new (u)int[] { MTU };
```

but it doesnt work either.
Meanwhile we don't have any ideas how to fix the problem.

I am grateful for every idea.

Thanks for your help and have a good day,
Alex

Edit:
Code to read the MTU should be (you have to tell this part a NetworkID so you don't read the Value of every NIC, you find this in your registry, but you should be able to delete the if part):

```
ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
{
    if (networkadapterID == (String)objMO["SettingID"])
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(objMO["MTU"]) + ": " + Convert.ToString(objMO["SettingID"]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Quote from the documentation: "This method is not supported."

Comment: if you open the Quote it will tell you that the minimum supported OS is Windows Vista, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/setmtu-method-in-class-win32-networkadapterconfiguration, so I think there should be usable.. but if not.. is there another option to solve this? We found somethin with a PowerShell command but this is only support with Windows 10 Computers

Comment: Based on my test, I can not change the MTU by using WMI. It seems that we can not set it, so I want to know if you can get the MTU. Because I even can not get the information about the MTU.

Comment: Yeah this works for us, but not really correctly.. maybe we have the next step, meanwhile we dont get an error while compiling and it seems that the programm changes the MTU (because return value is 1, and the documentation says it works and you have to reboot the computrer) but somehow not. Even after a reboot there is no change in registry with MTU, but if you read the MTU Value of this Object with the same ID as in registry it shows you the changed value. It's a bit complicated.. I will edit the Code to read the MTU Value in the original post, but I can't guarantee that it's 100% correct.

Comment: @Butterkeksm I also have tested the code you provided. I think may be the limit of system. I find that I can get the correct MTU from [IPv4InterfaceProperties.Mtu Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfaceproperties.mtu?view=netframework-4.8). However, the MTU filed can only get. Therefore, I surmise the MTU can not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

So far we didn't get the problem solved but we now check if the OS is Windows 10 and we will start a PowerShell task with this command:

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name 'NICName' -DisplayName 'Jumbo-Rahmen' | Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -RegistryValue  'MTUsize';
```

**Jumbo-Rahmen should be JumboPacket on an English OS**

If the OS is not Windows 10 the User will be asked to change the MTU manually